# How does one autohide a GWT MenuBar submenu?

Tags: java, events, gwt, menubar

We have recently attached a GWT MenuBar to a part of our application for, well, menu purposes.

Basically I want the sub menus to open when you mouse over the top level menu, which is easy enough to do:

```
menubar.setAutoOpen(true);
```

I would also like to have the sub menu automatically hide when the user's mouse leaves the sub menu. Ideally with some sort of delay to prevent it vanishing too abruptly, but I'd settle for just the hiding.

This doesn't seem to be built in and the MenuItem object in GWT directly subclasses UIObject which means there isn't a relatively trivial onBrowserEvent() or somewhere to attach mouse listeners. Possibly extending MenuItem and sinking/unsinking events would let me add this behavior, but I am unsure if that is the best approach.

So what would be the best approach to autohiding a GWT submenu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After much horrible hacking trying to achieve something similar we wrote our own [cascading menu](http://code.google.com/p/gwtportlets/source/browse/trunk/src/org/gwtportlets/portlet/client/ui/MenuPortlet.java) as part of the [GWT Portlets framework](http://code.google.com/p/gwtportlets/). It displays menu items and submenus from an HTML template looking something like this:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#submenu1()">Sub Menu 1</a>
<a href="#away">Away</a>

<div id="submenu1">
    <a href="#hello_world">Hello World</a>
    <a href="#free_memory">Free Memory</a>
    <a href="#submenu2()">Sub Menu 2</a>
</div>

<div id="submenu2">
    <a href="#command_demo">Command Demo</a>
    <a href="#command1()">Command1</a>
    <a href="#command2(arg1,arg2)">Command2</a>
</div>
```

The URLs that look like method calls broadcast CommandEvent's. The others trigger a history token change like normal. Have a look at the [online demo](http://095-beta.latest.gwtportletdemo.appspot.com/#command_demo) to see the menu in action.

Comment: Alas, horrible hacking is what we have had to do. I like the looks of the demo, but adding another framework to our project just isn't going to happen at this point. Thank you for the suggestion though, good to know this was out there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly complete solution, not perfect, explained after code:

```
public class MyMenuBar extends Composite {

    private class OpenTab implements ScheduledCommand {
        private String wid;

        public OpenTab(String windowId) {
            wid = windowId;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            WinUtl.newAppTab(wid);
        }
    }

    interface MyMenuBarUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyMenuBar> {}

    private static MyMenuBarUiBinder uiBinder =
                                GWT.create(MyMenuBarUiBinder.class);

    @UiField MenuBar mainMenu;

    @UiField MenuBar subsMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem subsChoice1;
    @UiField MenuItem subsChoice2;
    @UiField MenuItem subsChoice3;

    @UiField MenuBar svcPrvdrMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem svcPrvdrChoice1;
    @UiField MenuItem svcPrvdrChoice2;

    @UiField MenuBar netMgtMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem netMgtChoice1;

    @UiField MenuBar reportsMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem reportsChoice1;

    @UiField MenuBar auditsMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem auditsChoice1;

    @UiField MenuBar securityMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem securityChoice1;

    @UiField MenuBar helpMenu;
    @UiField MenuItem helpChoice1;

    private boolean subMenuPopped = false;
    private boolean subMenuEntered = false;

    private static Type<MouseOverHandler> OVR_EVT = MouseOverEvent.getType();
    private static Type<MouseOutHandler> OUT_EVT = MouseOutEvent.getType();

    private MouseOverHandler mainOverHandler = new MouseOverHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            subMenuPopped = true;
        }
    };

    private MouseOutHandler mainOutHandler = new MouseOutHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            Element e = event.getRelativeElement()
            boolean movedUp = (event.getRelativeY(e) < 0);
            if ((movedUp && subMenuPopped) || subMenuEntered) {
                subMenuPopped = false;
                subMenuEntered = false;
                mainMenu.closeAllChildren(true);
            }
        }
    };

    private MouseOverHandler subOverHandler = new MouseOverHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            subMenuEntered = true;
        }
    };

    private MouseOutHandler subOutHandler = new MouseOutHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            subMenuPopped = false;
            subMenuEntered = false;
            mainMenu.closeAllChildren(true);
        }
    };

    public MyMenuBar() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        mainMenu.addStyleName("npac-MenuBar");
        mainMenu.setAutoOpen(true);
        mainMenu.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        mainMenu.setFocusOnHoverEnabled(true);

        subsChoice1.setScheduledCommand(new OpenTab(Names.Wid.NPA));

        mainMenu.addDomHandler(mainOverHandler, OVR_EVT);
        mainMenu.addDomHandler(mainOutHandler, OUT_EVT);

        addHandlers(subsMenu);
        addHandlers(svcPrvdrMenu);
        addHandlers(netMgtMenu);
        addHandlers(reportsMenu);
        addHandlers(auditsMenu);
        addHandlers(securityMenu);
        addHandlers(helpMenu);
    }

    private void addHandlers(MenuBar m) {
        m.addDomHandler(subOverHandler, OVR_EVT);
        m.addDomHandler(subOutHandler, OUT_EVT);
    }
}
```

This handles the case where mouseOver opens subMenu, user then mouses UP, off mainMenu (subMenu closes). It does not handle the mouse moving diagonally down, past either side of subMenu (submenu stays open)
Certainly can be improved, but I just got it to work and wanted to share ;-)

Comment: This answer has helped me. I have use the idea and the code provided to build something very similar. Nevertheless, my menu has nested submenus (MenuBar in a MenuBar), which your code does not contemplate, and I'm still dealing with it... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for horrible hacking or relying on CSS within JAVA to achieve autohiding of a MenuBar with submenus. I created a fully working example of a Parent+Children dropdown menu with mouseover opening and mouseOut closing with explanations of each part for others to use.

The common problem I've witnessed folks having is Running a ((JMenu)e.getSource()).doClick(); on the mouseEntered simulates the click into one of the JMenu parents but can't be simply added to the mouseExited method as the MouseListener needs to be attached to the child MenuItems as well as the JMenu parents. (Which it doesn't do in the normal assignment to the MenuBar - only attaching to the parent JMenu objects).

Additionally, a problem arises due to trying to get the MouseExit listener to fire a "close" method ONLY when the mouse has left the entire Menu structure (ie the Child menu dropdowns).

**Below is a fully working answer taken from my live app:**

The way I solved the menu close on mouse out was to run a boolean variable "isMouseOut" in the top of the constructor to keep track, and then allocate the MouseListener in a more OO friendly way to keep track of the multiple MouseIn-MouseOut events as a user interacts with the menu. Which calls a separate menuClear method acting upon the state of the boolean "isMouseOut". The class implements MouseListener. This is how its done.

Create an ArrayList adding all the menu items to this array first. Like so:

```
    Font menuFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

// Array of MenuItems
    ArrayList<JMenuItem> aMenuItms = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
    JMenuItem mntmRefresh = new JMenuItem("Refresh");
    JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem mntmNormal = new JMenuItem("Normal");
    JMenuItem mntmMax = new JMenuItem("Max");
    JMenuItem mntmStatus = new JMenuItem("Status");
    JMenuItem mntmFeedback = new JMenuItem("Send Feedback");
    JMenuItem mntmEtsyTWebsite = new JMenuItem("EtsyT website");
    JMenuItem mntmAbout = new JMenuItem("About");

    aMenuItms.add(mntmRefresh);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmNew);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmNormal);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmMax);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmStatus);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmFeedback);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmEtsyTWebsite);
    aMenuItms.add(mntmAbout);
```

then iterate over the arrayList at this stage adding a MouseListener using the for() loop:

```
  for (Component c : aMenuItms) {
        if (c instanceof JMenuItem) {
            c.addMouseListener(ml);
        }
    }
```

Now set JMenu parents for the MenuBar:

```
// Now set JMenu parents on MenuBar
    final JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile).setFont(menuFont);
    final JMenu mnView = new JMenu("View");
    menuBar.add(mnView).setFont(menuFont);
    final JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp).setFont(menuFont);
```

Then add the dropdown menuItems children to the JMenu parents:

```
// Now set menuItems as children of JMenu parents
    mnFile.add(mntmRefresh).setFont(menuFont);
    mnFile.add(mntmNew).setFont(menuFont);
    mnView.add(mntmNormal).setFont(menuFont);
    mnView.add(mntmMax).setFont(menuFont);
    mnHelp.add(mntmStatus).setFont(menuFont);
    mnHelp.add(mntmFeedback).setFont(menuFont);
    mnHelp.add(mntmEtsyTWebsite).setFont(menuFont);
    mnHelp.add(mntmAbout).setFont(menuFont);
```

Add the mouseListeners to the JMenu parents as a separate step:

```
    for (Component c : menuBar.getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JMenu) {
            c.addMouseListener(ml);
        }
    }
```

Now that the child menuItem elements all have their own listeners that are separate to the parent JMenu elements and the MenuBar itself - It is important to identify the object type within the MouseListener() instantiation so that you get the menu auto opening on mouseover (in this example the 3x JMenu parents) BUT ALSO avoids child exception errors and allows clean identification of mouseOUT of the menu structure without trying to monitor where the mouse position is.  The MouseListener is as follows:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            isMouseOut = true;
            timerMenuClear();
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            isMouseOut = false;
            Object eSource = e.getSource();
            if(eSource == mnHelp || eSource == mnView || eSource == mnFile){
                ((JMenu) eSource).doClick();
            }
        }
    };
```

The above only simulates the mouse click into the JMenu 'parents' (3x in this example) as they are the triggers for the child menu dropdowns.  The timerMenuClear() method calls on the MenuSelectionManager to empty whatever selectedpath point was live at the time of real mouseOUT:

```
public void timerMenuClear(){
    ActionListener task = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if(isMouseOut == true){
              System.out.println("Timer");
          MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath();
          }
      }
  };        
    //Delay timer half a second to ensure real mouseOUT
  Timer timer = new Timer(1000, task); 
  timer.setInitialDelay(500);        
  timer.setRepeats(false);
  timer.start();
}
```

It took me a little testing, monitoring what values I could access within the JVM during its development - but it Works a treat! even with nested menus  :)  I hope many find this full example very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class MenuBarExt extends MenuBar {

public MenuBarExt()
{
    super();
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
{
    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event))
    {
        case Event.ONMOUSEOUT:
            closeAllChildren(false);
            break;
        default:
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            break;

    } 
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
}

}
```

Comment: Works great!   Except when you want to actually select a menu item and the menu goes away...